# Flutter Cloud firestore return result

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

Hello i have this small problem on my firebase, I can retrieve data from the cloud firestore but what i want is to store it in a function and return it and display to another class.

```
class 1
Future displayData() async{
    fireStoreInstance.collection("user").getDocuments().then((querySnapshot) {
      querySnapshot.documents.forEach((result) {
          return result.data; //this does not work
      });
    });
  }

**************************

class 2 display data
 IconButton(
   icon: Icon(Ionicons.ios_search,),
     onPressed: () async{
         List list; 
          var q = await db.displayData();
           list = q;
           print(list); // it returns null
        }
    ),
```

Comment: please help me guys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `async/await` instead of `then`:

```
Future displayData() async{
    return await fireStoreInstance.collection("user").getDocuments(); 
  }
```

Then inside `onPressed`, do the following:

```
     onPressed: () async{
          var q = await db.displayData();
           q.documents.forEach((result) {
           print(result.data);
        }
    ),
```

Comment: it still returns null

Comment: do you have a collection called user?

Comment: what if i will assign result.data into list ?

Comment: inside forEach assign it what do you get/

Comment: Unhandled Exception: type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<dynamic>'